# Tab Delimited csv instead of comma delimited in scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am currently using the command

```
scrapy crawl myspider -o output.csv -t csv
```

to get output csv files. These files by default are comma delimited. How do i get a tab delimited file instead?

Comment: There seems to be a hacky solution discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scrapy-users/KTkP9kehoPI/OGbd7-pPKqMJ

Comment: It's not really a hack, rather a customization of the default CSV exporter https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/exporter/__init__.py#L168

Answer (score 2):

Use this solution to override Scrapy's default CSV writer delimiter.

**scraper/exporters.py**

```py
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter


class CsvCustomSeperator(CsvItemExporter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['encoding'] = 'utf-8'
        kwargs['delimiter'] = '\t'
        super(CsvCustomSeperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**scraper/settings.py**

```py
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'csv': 'scraper.exporters.CsvCustomSeperator'
}
```

**In terminal**

```
$ scrapy crawl spider -o file.csv
```